# Separate Django user model from Wagtail user model

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Is there a way to separate the general Django auth user model and the Wagtail auth user model?

I'm including a wagtail blog app in my already existing Django project but I've been asked to create a separate user model for the blog app and I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8.1/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html) help you?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Django does not provide any way to have multiple user models active at the same time. What exact problem are you trying to solve here? (In other words: what is special about your project that makes two user models necessary?)

Comment: @gasman It's something they asked me to do if it was possible, just because they want the website users to be apart from the blog users. I did my research but didn't find anything useful and wondered if the StackOverflow community had any different answers.

Comment: this blog post might help you: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

could you possibly use the django permissions?